Firebase Phone Number Authentication doesn't work no matter what
I am creating a login with firebase, the one with phone number, I have set up everything correctly, yes I have enabled phone sign in.
I get invalid credentials error, it is working fine with fictional number, but with real number it is not working,
It gets stuck on signInWithPhoneNumber method, I don't know what credentials are wrong, the firebase config is working fine for google email auth, firestore, storage and all..
I tried exporting auth form config, then tried creating it on the signin page by itself.
Method 1
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { RecaptchaVerifier, signInWithPhoneNumber } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from '../firebase';

const PhoneAuth = () => {
    const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');
    const [verificationCode, setVerificationCode] = useState('');
    const [confirmationResult, setConfirmationResult] = useState(null);
    const [isCodeSent, setIsCodeSent] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState('');

    const initializeRecaptcha = () => {
        console.log('Here 1')
        if (!window.recaptchaVerifier) {
            console.log('Here 2')
            window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
                'size': 'invisible',
                'callback': (response) => {
                    // Handle reCAPTCHA response if needed
                },
                'expired-callback': () => {
                    setError('reCAPTCHA expired. Please try again.');
                }
            }, auth);
            console.log('Here 3')
        }
    };
    
    const onSignInSubmit = () => {
        console.log('Here 4')
        initializeRecaptcha(); // Initialize reCAPTCHA before making the sign-in request
        console.log('Here 5')
        
        const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
        console.log('Here 6')
        signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, phoneNumber, appVerifier)
        .then((result) => {
            setConfirmationResult(result);
            setIsCodeSent(true);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error sending SMS:', error);
            setError('Error sending SMS. Please try again.');
        });
        console.log('Here 7')
    };
    
    const onVerifyCodeSubmit = () => {
        console.log('Here 8')
        if (confirmationResult) {
            console.log('Here 9')
            confirmationResult.confirm(verificationCode)
                .then((result) => {
                    const user = result.user;
                    console.log('User signed in:', user);
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Error verifying code:', error);
                    setError('Invalid verification code. Please try again.');
                });
        }
    };
console.log(phoneNumber)
    return (
        <div>
            <div id="recaptcha-container"></div>
            {!isCodeSent ? (
                <div>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter phone number"
                        value={phoneNumber}
                        onChange={(e) => setPhoneNumber(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <button onClick={onSignInSubmit}>Send Verification Code</button>
                </div>
            ) : (
                <div>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter verification code"
                        value={verificationCode}
                        onChange={(e) => setVerificationCode(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <button onClick={onVerifyCodeSubmit}>Verify Code</button>
                </div>
            )}
            {error && <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error}</p>}
        </div>
    );
};

export default PhoneAuth;


Method 2
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-input-2'
import 'react-phone-input-2/lib/style.css'
import { RecaptchaVerifier, signInWithPhoneNumber } from 'firebase/auth'
import { auth } from '../firebase/setup'
function PhoneSignin() {
    const [phone, setPhone] = useState("")
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
    const [otp, setOtp] = useState("")
    console.log(phone)

    const sendOtp = async () =>{
        try{
            const recaptcha = await new RecaptchaVerifier(auth, "recaptcha", {})
            console.log('ssssss', auth, phone, recaptcha)
            const confirmation = await signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, phone, recaptcha)
            setUser(confirmation)
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error.message)
        }
    }

    const verifyOtp = async () =>{
        try {
            await user.confirm(otp)
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
  return (
    <div>
        <div>
        <PhoneInput
    country={'us'}
    value={phone}
    onChange={(phone) => setPhone('+'+ phone)}
  />
  <button onClick={sendOtp}> Send OTP</button>
  <div id="recaptcha" style={{marginTop:'5px'}}></div>
  <input onChange={(e) => setOtp(e.target.value)} placeholder='enter otp' />
    <button onClick={verifyOtp}>Verify</button>
    </div>
    
    </div>
  )
}

export default PhoneSignin

I have even followed youtube tutorials, forked git hub repos, tried different projects in firebase, even different firebase account.
